# C++ Invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

I wanted to pass-in functions as arguments to a templated function without having any indirection. To achieve this I created two nested structs, each defining the function I wish to pass in to the templated function. Each of the structs accesses data members from the outside `class B`:

```
namespace A{
    class B{
        public:
            B();

            template <typename T>
            void templatedFunction(T t){
                //I pass one of the struct objects in to here, to invoke the desired function 
                t();
            }

        private:
            struct X{
                void operator(){
                    do();
                }

                void do(){
                    //Accesses the data members of class B
                    e->doSomething();
                }
            };

            struct Y{
                void operator(){
                    do();
                }

                void do(){
                    //Accesses the data members of class B
                    d.doSomething();
                }
            };

            C* c;
            D d;
            E* e;
    };
}
```

and the compiler errors I get are pretty much all of the format:

> error: invalid use of non-static data member B::d

for the lines within the struct accessing the class data members and on the lines declaring the data members in `B`.

Comment: Shouldn't you call the functor in templatedFunction like this: `t()`?

Comment: Thanks- had to type the code out from scratch.

Comment: Rolled back the latest edit because it invalidated an already posted anaswer. **Don't do that**. Don't change the code or question after answers have been posted, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested class in C++ does not (automatically) have access to an instance of the containing class. It's just a class definition like any other. You need a `B` instance to access non-static data members of `B`.

---

You can restructure your nested class `Y` as

```
struct Y
{
    void operator()( B& b ){
        do( b );
    }

    void do( B& b ){
        //Accesses the data members of class B
        b.d.doSomething();
    }
};
```

and fix your function template and calls, and class `X`, accordingly.

Note that your presented code for `operator()`, with no argument list, would not have compiled, but I'm not downvoting since you are stopped by another compilation error (i.e., possibly it is the real code you're showing).

Comment: Is there really no other solution than passing an instance of B?

Comment: I understand why I'd get compiler errors accessing the members from the structs. I dont understand why this would cause compiler errors for the lines of variable declaration within B?

Comment: @user997112: Well any blanket statement of "impossible" tends to be disproved sooner or later, regardless of the subject matter, so I won't say that. But I can't think of any practical other solution right now. It may however be evident when more of the context of the question is considered, but unfortunately that context is not specified.

Comment: My over-arching problem is that I wish to pass in one of two functions as arguments to be executed within another function. However, I want to avoid the overhead of the pointer indirection from function pointers.

Comment: @user997112: Well the member functions can and will probably be inlined, thus avoiding the function pointer "overhead". However, in any situation when apparently efficiency considerations are dictating the design, it can be a good idea to **MEASURE**. Get some numbers on the table.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a struct (or class for that matter) nested in another class, it it not treated specially in any way. It works exactly the same as if the struct was defined outside of the enclosing class. The only thing which is different is the scope of nested class name. So, if you have

```
class A { class B{}; };
```

and

```
class B{}; class A {};
```

the only difference is that outside class `A` you need to name the class `B` as `A::B` in the first case, and just `B` in the second class. There is no other difference, and in particular class `B` does not gain any special access to class `A` members.

Comment: So how do I access members of A from within B (first case)?

Comment: In the same way as you would do it in the second case. You need e.g. to pass the reference to `A` to member function of `B`.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: at least visual c++ and g++ disagree with the quoted statement. i'm sure you can find the relevant standardese. note that there's been a bit back and forth about the rules, but i'm not sure if that has happened after the first iso standard (in 1998).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Care to give an example? The C++11 text in 9.7 talks only about the scope, nothing else ("A class can be declared within another class. A class declared within another is called a nested class. The name of a nested class is local to its enclosing class. The nested class is in the scope of its enclosing class.")

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You disagree with the statement "B does not gain any special access to class A members". Show us a conformant example showing that B _does_ get some kind of special access.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: why don't you cook up an example yourself, huh. i'm getting tired of spoonfeeding SO readers all the time.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I cannot provide examples supporting your statements. You should do it to prove that they were correct. Or maybe they weren't?